# Why Code-128 with ^SF have one more digit?

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl-ii

I have a problem with `^BC` barcode using ZPL II.

My code looks like:

```
^XA
^LL248
^PW480

^BY1
^FO15,10
^BCN,100
^FC%,{,#^FD%y%m%d%H%M%S000^SF%%%%%%%%%%%%ddd,1^FS

^PQ5
^XZ
```

And for example the 5th label looks like this:
[image: 5th label]

And my question is, why I have additional 0 between date/hour and serial number.
This sample code should look like 220929093311**004** but it have four digits after date/time 220929093311**0004**.

Comment: I've just tested your code on a ZD620 300dpi (I just had to increase the BY value from 1 to 3 otherwise the barcode was too small) and this is what I'm getting https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mB8HFw6J9iy01YmqNVRT-9ECQUqq-SFR/view?usp=sharing
As you can see the additional 0 is not added.
How are you sending the code?
Can you test the code using the "open communication with printer" in zebra setup utilities?

Comment: At the moment I'm using Honeywell PC42d with ZSim (ZPL-II command language simulator) so problem could be related to this Honeywell simulator. I'm sending text file from windows command line using copy label.txt \\localhost\printer

Comment: that should be ok, but I would do some proper test on an actual printer. The simulator may process the data differently and lead to wrong conclusions